# How to create a custom express request to test with supertest

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, ts-jest, supertest

I am trying to call a function from my app using supertest and sending a custom express request but I am getting a 422 Error when I send my request.

This is my custom express request

```
export interface CreateGroupRequest extends Request {
    body: {
        groupName: string;
        email: string;
        country: string;
    };
```

This is my mock request

```
                var testCreateGroupRequest: CreateGroupRequest = {
                   body: {
                        groupName: testName,
                        email: email,
                        country: 'US',
                    }
                } as Request
```

This is my test so far

```
 await supertest(app)
                .post("/login")
                .send(testLoginBody)
                .expect(200)
                .then((response) => {
                    sessionToken = response.body.token
                }).then(() => {
                    supertest(app)
                        .post("/create_group")
                        .set('X-JWT-Token', `${sessionToken}`)
                        .send(testCreateGroupRequest)
                        .then((response) => {
                             console.log({response})
                        })
                })
```

The message that is in the response is "body.groupName\" is required". How should I be creating the custom request?

Comment: Why are you assuming the tests are wrong? What if your code is the one that has unexpected behavior? Can you show us your relevant code so we can all sleep comfortable at night?

Comment: I am assuming the test is wrong because of the message from the response which I am assuming is because it is not reading the request. What relevant code would you like the see? my express app?

Comment: Your `/login` route, so we can be sure that your code isn't the problem and that it is indeed the test not working.

Comment: I can assure you the login route works. The create group route is extending the already working login route. It is there to generate the JWT token to allow a user to call /create_group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one of `supertest`'s examples:

```js
describe('POST /users', function() {
  it('responds with json', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/users')
      .send({name: 'john'})
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        if (err) return done(err);
        return done();
      });
  });
});
```

Notice that in their `send` method, they *directly send the body*.
They don't extend or make their own `Request`.

So to fix your issue you just need to send the body and not the fake request:

```
supertest(app)
    .post("/create_group")
    .set('X-JWT-Token', `${sessionToken}`)
    .send({
        groupName: testName,
        email: email,
        country: 'US',
    })
    .set('Accept', 'application/json') // Don't forget the header for JSON!
    .then(console.log) // Shortened
```